# Decrease space between spirals

Tags: bezier-curves

I want to decrease the space(shown by blue arrows) between green spirals so that it looks a bit spherical, currently it looks a bit stretched. Any guess how blender provides this option to do it.

[image]

Comment: I remember that when I had created this, it had option "height" but now I am not able to find that option

Comment: Can you not just highlight all geometry and stretch?

Comment: Tried that but it is changing all the object, so basically it just enlarging or shrinking it. But I want the radius same just need to decrease the height only

Comment: Sorry, I meant scale but just on one axis. Depending on how you made your object, you might be able to scale along the local z axis to shrink just the height. If not, reorient your geometry to the global axis and then just scale along Z

Comment: Thanks @Lewis meanwhile I was searching the options then I found same as suggested by you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I was just finding out each option in the blender and suddenly found the option "Object" tab marked in the picture by with  a "1". Then scaled the object around only the required axes.

Amid Lewis commented same answer above on my question.

I was trying the scaling using <kbd>S</kbd> key but the mouse was not able to do it with small extent, and I gotya the option while searching.

[image: object tab of the properties panel]